# Magento configurable product price calculation, based on chosen attribute

Tags: php, javascript, attributes, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I don't know if this is possible, I do really hope so however.
I have created a configurable product with some attributes.
One of the attribute is: size, for example 40x40, 50x50 and 60x60.
Now a second attribute is color, for example green and red.

The base price is €100.
Red has an extra charge of 10% and 50x50 and 60x60 has fixed price of respectively €110 and €120.
Now this 10% is calculated on the base price, and that's exactly what I don't want. Because if I choose 60x60, the price is €120 + 10% of the base price = €130. But it should be €120 + 10% = €132.

Does anyone know a solution for this? I used the extension "[Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)" but that extension has so many bugs that I can't use it at all.

So if anyone could help me, I would appreciate that very much!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it is just very impossible to do so. After many days of testing and looking for solutions, I found a great extension that solved my problem. It just takes the prices from the simple products instead from the configurable products.

Extension URL: [Ayasoftware](http://www.ayasoftware.com/content/magento-simple-product-pricing)

Answer (score 2):

There is another extension available that can also do the work. It's able to recover product custom fields together with other basic data and calculate the final price using excel formulas, so you're free to build complex calculations. I share the link in case it may help
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/xlspricecalculator.html